# The probability distribution for the sum of a large number of point scatterers

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

I have a number of independent and identically distributed random variables $X_{1},X_{2},...,X_{n}$, uniformly distributed on the interval $[0,2\pi)$.

I am interested in understanding the distribution of $\left|\sum_{j=1}^{n}e^{iX_{j}}\right|$, particularly as $n\to\infty$. Each term represents the phase due to a point scatterer, so I'm interested in understanding how they combine when there are a large number of them.

Clearly, if $n=1$, the distribution as a Dirac-delta centred at unity.

If $n=2$, I'm able to use the fact that $\left|e^{iX_{1}}+e^{iX_{2}}\right|=2\left|cos\left(\frac{X_{1}-X_{2}}{2}\right)\right|$ and the CDF method to show that the distribution is $\frac{2}{\pi\sqrt{4-x^{2}}}$ for $0<x<2$.

However, beyond this I'm struggling. I'm not sure if there's an inductive way to get the behaviour as $n\to\infty$ or whether there's a way of getting there without calculating the distribution for each $n$ along the way.

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: Do you need the exact distribution or some asymptotic results as $n \to \infty$?  If asymptotics are okay, the results will follow from standard theory of random walks - I'm having trouble working them out on the fly but I'm hoping someone sees this comment and helps you.

Comment: It is the limit that's of most interest to me (and for which I will accept an answer). An answer for general n is a 'nice-to-have', though not essential (and may be too difficult?).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$$\begin{align}
L&:= \left|\sum_{j=1}^n e^{iX_j}\right| \\
&= \left|\sum_{j=1}^n \cos(X_j) + i \sum_{j=1}^n \sin(X_j)\right|\\
&=\sqrt{\left(\sum_{j=1}^n \cos(X_j)\right)^2+\left(\sum_{j=1}^n \sin(X_j)\right)^2}\\
&=n\cdot \sqrt{\left(\underbrace{\frac{1}{n}\sum_{j=1}^n \cos(X_j)}_{P_n}\right)^2+\left(\underbrace{\frac{1}{n}\sum_{j=1}^n \sin(X_j)}_{Q_n}\right)^2}\\
\end{align}$$

---

According to the CLT, we have
$$\sqrt{n}\left(\pmatrix{P_n\\Q_n}-\mu  \right)\xrightarrow[n\to+\infty]{\mathcal{D}}\mathcal{N}_2\left(\pmatrix{0\\0},\Sigma\right)$$
where $\mu \in \mathbb{R}^{2}$ the mean value of $(\cos(X),\sin(X))'$ and $\Sigma\in \mathbb{R}^{2\times 2}$ the covariance variance of $(\cos(X),\sin(X))'$.
It's easy to calculate that
$$\mu = \pmatrix{0\\0} \hspace{1cm}\text{and }\hspace{1cm} \Sigma = \pmatrix{1/2 & 0 \\ 0 &1/2}$$
then we deduce
$$\iff \color{red}{ \sqrt{n}\pmatrix{P_n\\Q_n} \xrightarrow[n\to+\infty]{\mathcal{D}}\mathcal{N}_2\left(\pmatrix{0\\0},\pmatrix{1/2 & 0 \\ 0 &1/2}\right)}\stackrel{\mathcal{D}}{:=}\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\pmatrix{U\\V}$$
That is, the vector $\sqrt{n}\pmatrix{P_n\\Q_n}$ converges in distribution to $1/\sqrt 2$ of a standard bivariate normal distribution.

---

Let us denote $g(x,y) = x^2 +y^2$, we will try to apply the [multivariate delta method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Delta_method#Multivariate_delta_method) at the point $(x,y=(0,0)$. As the gradient $\nabla g$ is equal to $(0,0)$ at $(x,y)=(0,0)$, we use rather the [second-order delta method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Delta_method#Second-order_delta_method):
$$n\left(g(P_n,Q_n)-g(0,0)\right)\stackrel{\mathcal{D}}{\approx} \frac{n}{2}\pmatrix{P_n\\Q_n}'\pmatrix{2&0\\0&2}\pmatrix{P_n\\Q_n}  \hspace{1cm}\text{when } n\to +\infty$$

$$\iff n \cdot g(P_n,Q_n) \xrightarrow[n\to+\infty]{\mathcal{D}} \frac{1}{2}\cdot  \frac{1}{\sqrt 2}\cdot \frac{1}{\sqrt 2} \pmatrix{U& V} \pmatrix{2&0\\0&2}\pmatrix{U\\V} = \frac{1}{2}(U^2+V^2)$$

As $L=n\sqrt{g(P_n,Q_n)}$, we deduce then:
$$\color{red}{\frac{L}{\sqrt{n}}\xrightarrow[n\to+\infty]{\mathcal{D}} \frac{1}{ \sqrt{2}} \sqrt{U^2 + V^2}  \stackrel{\mathcal{D}}{=}  \frac{1}{ \sqrt{2}}\chi_2 }$$

We can conclude that asymptotically $L/\sqrt{n}$ converges to a [chi distribution.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chi_distribution) of degree $2$.